# Windows phone 8 DataTemplate in XAML not showing data

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, datatemplate

I would like to display some information in a data template in my app but when it is run it shows nothing in the listbox.

Here is the class code (class called notes)

```
public class notes
{
    public string strNoteName { get; set; }
    public string strCreated { get; set; }
    public string strModified { get; set; }
    public bool boolIsProtected { get; set; }
    public string strNoteImage { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<notes> GetnotesRecord()
    {
        ObservableCollection<notes> notesRecord = new ObservableCollection<notes>  
       {  
           new notes{strNoteName="Science",strCreated="17/07/2014",strModified="17/07/2014",boolIsProtected=true,strNoteImage=""},  
           new notes{strNoteName="Math",strCreated="12/02/2014",strModified="15/07/2014",boolIsProtected=false,strNoteImage=""},  
           new notes{strNoteName="HW",strCreated="05/06/2014",strModified="2/07/2014",boolIsProtected=false,strNoteImage=""},  
           new notes{strNoteName="Business",strCreated="23/04/2014",strModified="17/07/2014",boolIsProtected=true,strNoteImage=""},

       };
        return notesRecord;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<notes> _notes;
    public ObservableCollection<notes> allNotes
    {
        get
        {
            return _notes;
        }
        set
        {
            _notes = value;

        }
    }    

}
```

And here is the XAML code:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,10,0,88">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding strNoteImage}" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Width="150" Height="100" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding strNoteName}" Margin="5,1,0,1"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding strCreated}" Margin="5,1,0,1"></TextBlock>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Last modified: " Margin="5,1,0,1"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding strModified}" Margin="3,1,0,1"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Is protected: " Margin="5,1,0,1"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding boolIsProtected}" Margin="3,1,0,1"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>

                        </StackPanel>


                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox  >
```

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: First of all why you are binding boolIsProtected to Image?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that too. here is the updated code @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ListBox definition to

```
<ListBox Margin="0,10,0,88" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

and set in C# code

```
this.DataContext = Notes.GetnotesRecord();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to set the ItemsSource to the Listbox,

You can do that in XAML and set the DataContext in code behind , Something like this,

```
<ListBox Margin="0,10,0,88" Name = "lstBox1" ItemsSource= "{Binding}" />
```

In code behind,

```
  This.DataContext = GetnotesRecord();
```

Or

```
   lstBox1.ItemsSource = GetnotesRecord();
```

Comment: When added `Name = "lstBox1" ItemsSource= {Binding}` there is an error saying  "{ is not a valid name"

Comment: ItemSource should have "" around the binding statement. Like  ItemsSource="{Binding}"